# Apache server: localhost keeps loading forever

Tags: apache2

I have installed apache using following command

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

After that I start the server with this command

```
 sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

This did run the server and everything worked perfectly. But after the first time, I restart the server using the same command and this time localhost keeps loading forever. No page or anything is shown in localhost. It just keeps loading. Why this is happening and whats the solution?

Comment: Are you sure the commands you wrote on your question are correct?

Comment: Please check the status of the server with: `sudo service apache2 status`